# passing form arguments in django

Tags: django, forms, django-queryset

I am trying to implement a simple search function in django but somehow I can't pass the argument from my template to my view function. I've got a key error: KeyError at /artdb/search/ because kwargs is empty:

url.py:

```
    path('search/',views.Search.as_view(),name='search'),
```

base,.html:

```
 <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" name="search" action="{% url 'artdb:search' %}" {{ form.as_p }} method="get">{% csrf_token %}
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" value="{{seastr}}">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" value="{{seastr}}">Search</button>
    </form>
```

views.py:

```
class Search(ListView):
    print("class Search")
    model=Person
    template_name='artdb/search.html'
    context_object_name='ans'

def get_queryset(self):
    Pdb().set_trace()
    self.seastr=get_object_or_404(Person,name=self.kwargs['seastr'])
    return Person.objects.filter(seastr=self.seastr)
```

Comment: Well you likely first fetch the page *without* filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not attach the name `seastr` to your `<input>` field:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" name="search" action="{% url 'artdb:search' %}" {{ form.as_p }} method="get">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="seastr" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" value="{{seastr}}">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Notice the `name="seastr"` in the `<input>` tag.

GET parameters are not stored in `self.kwargs`, but in `self.request.GET`, so we can obtain the parameter with `self.request.GET['seastr']`.

Typically the page with the search bar, is the same as the one with the request, therefore the search request if frequently *optional*. So it might be useful to make filtering optional here:

```
class Search(ListView):
    model=Person
    template_name='artdb/search.html'
    context_object_name='ans'

    def get_queryset(self):
        q = self.request.GET.get('seastr')
        if q is not None:
            return Person.objects.filter(seastr=q)
        else:
            return Person.objects.all()
```

Finally note that the `seastr` parameter is *not* part of the context data. You can make this part of the context data, by patching it:

```
class Search(ListView):
    model=Person
    template_name='artdb/search.html'
    context_object_name='ans'

    def get_queryset(self):
        q = self.request.GET.get('seastr')
        if q is not None:
            return Person.objects.filter(seastr=q)
        else:
            return Person.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['seastr'] = self.request.GET.get('seastr')
        return context
```

Comment: ok, thanks. I changed this also: return Person.objects.filter(firstName__icontains=q)
and now it works.